# LTSpice PWL loop

Tags: analog

I want to loop a PWL with my file for ever.

My schematic looks like this :

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 352 80 96 80
WIRE 96 128 96 80
WIRE 352 128 352 80
FLAG 352 208 0
FLAG 96 208 0
SYMBOL voltage 96 112 R0
WINDOW 3 74 2 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PWL file=data
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL res 336 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
TEXT 168 160 Left 2 !.tran 5
TEXT 32 40 Left 2 !PWL repeat forever file=data endrepeat
```

My file is named "data" (no extension) placed in the same directory as the sch and is:

```
0 1
1 3
2 4
3 -1
4 1
```

I get this error:

```
Circuit: * C:\LTspiceXVII\Filter_modTest\Loop.asc

Error on line 5 : pwl repeat forever file=data endrepeat
     Unable to find definition of model "endrepeat"
Fatal Error: Missing resistance per length of coupled transmission line model "P"
```

I have verified that LTSpice is able to rad and use my "data" file if I remove the spice directive:

```
PWL repeat forever file=data endrepeat
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Now it's better. When you have text that can be interpreted as code, use ``` as delimiters for the text (it needs to be ``` <text_goes_here> ```).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the parenthesis, or the quotes, but only if the path has no spaces (e.g. `/path/to/file1.txt` works, `/path/to/file 1.txt` will fail). This works for me:

```
* file: data
0 1
1 3
2 4
3 -1
4 1
```

```
PWL repeat forever file="data" endrepeat
PWL repeat for 3 file="data" endrepeat ; this works, too
```

Note that the file has no extension, since it's not mandatory. But, if you're on Windows, it's known to hide the extensions, by default, so you'll have to account for that. Also, there is no path because the file resides in the same folder. If it was elsewhere then you would need to add the path: `file=/path/to/elsewhere/data`.

---

[edit]

Now it's a better. Now it's clear that you used the `file=` syntax for the `PWL()` source, but you didn't use it as I've written it, above. Instead, you added a SPICE directive. This is interpreted by LTspice to be a netlist entry, with the first character being a SPICE element -- **not** a `PWL()` source. In this case, `P` stands for an [undocumented lossy transmission line](https://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#Lossy_Transmission_Lines) and, since the rest of the characters do not follow the required syntax, it complains (the parser interprets `endrepeat` to be the `.model` name, hence the error).

Here is the reworked version:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 352 80 96 80
WIRE 96 128 96 80
WIRE 352 128 352 80
FLAG 352 208 0
FLAG 96 208 0
SYMBOL voltage 96 112 R0
WINDOW 3 -21 139 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PWL repeat forever file=data endrepeat
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL res 336 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
TEXT 96 24 Left 2 !.tran 10
```

As you can see, the `repeat` keyword needs to be added to the `PWL` line, it's part of the syntax for the `PWL`. The `data` file has not been altered.

Comment: It does not work for me, strange, here what i get:    

Error on line 5 : pwl repeat forever file=test endrepeat
  Unable to find definition of model "endrepeat"
Fatal Error: Missing resistance per length of coupled transmission line model "P"

The file works fine without the spice directive: 

PWL repeat forever file=test endrepeat

I just cannot make the loop to work.

Comment: @Alessandro Can you post the contents of the file `test`? I suspect you have some lines that do not obey the syntax.

Comment: @a concerned citizen It is actually the same as posted above
0 1
1 3
2 4
3 -1
4 1

Comment: @Alessandro So, to be clear: you have two files, `x.asc` (or whatever name for the schematic) and `test` (no extension), both in the same directory/location. Is this true? Because that *error on line 5* looks suspicious, as if you have something else. As if the `PWL` is a line in a netlist. These are details that you should have told beforehand, not something I have to pry out from you.

Comment: @a concerned citizen I have a schematic named pdm_test.asc, and a file named test.txt, both in the same directory. The PWL is a spice directive in the schematic.

Comment: @Alessandro If the file has a `.txt` extension but the `PWL` line uses `file=text` then you can't expect it to load. LTspice doesn't need extensions means the *files*, themselves, as they appear in your computer, don't need extensions, but whatever the *filename* they have, it must appear *exactly* the same in the `file=` line. So if your file is `test.txt` then you must have `file=test.txt`, and if the file is `test` then the line needs to be `file=test`.

Comment: @a concerned citizen I got that, I have changed that as you recommended in the very beginning, so yes, I have done that and I have followed exactly what you have described, still getting the same error.  That is why I wrote "strange". I have seen similar example the syntax and it should work.

Comment: @Alessandro Can you describe in steps what you did (and update your question)? Here are mine: 1) create file `data` (w/o extension, here without) 2) fill it with `0 1 1 3 2 4 3 -1 4 1` (nothing else!) 3) create `x.asc` in the same folder as `data` 4) place voltage source (press `'V'`) 5) write `PWL repeat forever file=data endrepeat`  instead of the default value 6) add `.tran 10` 7) run simulation.

Comment: @a concerned citizen here is the sch:
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 352 80 96 80
WIRE 96 128 96 80
WIRE 352 128 352 80
FLAG 352 208 0
FLAG 96 208 0
SYMBOL voltage 96 112 R0
WINDOW 3 74 2 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PWL file=data
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL res 336 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
TEXT 168 160 Left 2 !.tran 5
TEXT 32 40 Left 2 !PWL repeat forever file=data endrepeat

stil the same error.

Comment: @Alessandro This is not working like this. [Edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/631223/edit) your question and include *all* the additional information that you think it's needed in order to get a proper answer. I can't tell which is what in there. Use ``` as delimiters for the text. Take the [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this site works. See the examples offered in how to format your question, when editing. If you want help, help us help you. It's reciprocal.

Comment: @a concerned citizen Thanks for you patience, as you can see I am new with this, so a lot to learn ;) .I have update my question and added all the info(hopefully)

Comment: @a concerned citizen, Thank you very much for your help. Works perfectly!

Comment: @Alessandro I'm glad it does but, as I suggested, please take [the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this site works (yes, it's a hint).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Mike Englehardt 2003 PWL loop]

This from googling is an alternative way by [Mike Englehardt](https://maker.pro/forums/threads/ltspice-pwl-that-loops-forever.25216/#post-198074).  Setup your (singular) PWL file as I1, then set the repeat interval in B2.

Then use V(x) in place of the data.

Comment: 2003, good times. Fortunately, nowadays the `PWL` allows the use of the `repeat` keyword with files, so it can be achieved with only one element/node.